# Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I am using SQL Server 2008 import and export wizard. I need to import a database. I opened the SQL server import/export wizard and I went through the following actions:-

1. for the destination I chose "SQL server native client 10".
2. then I selected copy data from one or more tables or view.
3. SSIS run immediately

but i got the following errors,

> Operation stopped...
>
> - Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)
> - Initializing Connections (Success)
> - Setting SQL Command (Success)
> - Setting Source Connection (Success)
> - Setting Destination Connection (Success)
> - Validating (Error)
>
> Messages Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into
>   the read-only column "ActionID".  (SQL Server Import and Export
>   Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination -
>   AuditActions" (22)" failed validation and returned validation status
>   "VS_ISBROKEN".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

It seems that I can not import identity columns and timestamps columns, so how I can force these values to be imported?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Before Importing date execute the below query to set identity insert on:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
```

Then do the import operations.

After importing date execute the below query to set identity insert off:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF
```

Answer (score 256):

With all due respect to Kishore's answer, that approach is valid if you're modifying the packages. Since you're using the import/export wizard, the more straight forward approach would be to check the `Enable Identity Insert` box on the Column Mappings tab.

In the Import Export Wizard, after selecting the table for copy, click the `Edit Mappings...` button

[image]

In the resulting screen, click the `Enable identity insert` property and your identities will be replicated over.

[image]

Same net result as issuing `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON` & OFF but this is done automagically at build time.

Comment: thanks the identity columns problem is solved, and now i am having problems with timestamps columns. any idea what i can do with them ?

Comment: Timestamps are mentioned here: http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Common%20Issues%20with%20the%20SQL%20Server%20Import%20and%20Export%20Wizard.aspx

Comment: If you're importing multiple tables, you can select multiple tables in the list, and then click Edit Mappings to make the Enable identity insert option apply to all selected tables in a single click.

Comment: Kishore solution hasn't solved my problem but the one you offers does. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wonder after exporting if it is needed to do:SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName OFF. Thanks.

Comment: I have first modified the table to remove the primary key constraint, then truncate the table. After I have done both of them I then run the export tool. Had I know this earlier, I would save a lot of time.

Comment: Try it again on a different table, the export process was stopped by "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblNote'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblNote'. The duplicate key value is (1).".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the box of Keep Identity in connection manager pane of Destination  connection, when creating a data flow string. It worked for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJSl1.png)