# data conversion from MySQL to SQL in SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-conversion

I need to transfer some tables from MySQL to SQL DB. I have an ID column (data type: bigint) in MySQL which is starting from 1 and it grows incrementally. I created a bigint column in the destination table in the SQL DB, but when the filling is done, the data is randomly changing:

```
source column
-1
-2
-3

ideal destination column
-1
-2
-3

what really happens  
-65 
-34345 
-87643
```

The ODBC connector is set to Unicode.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you please provide some more details?  Is the ID column an identity in SQL?  Is identity insert on?  The insert is being performed with an OLEDB destination?  Is the id column mapped correctly?

Comment: I don't touch mysql but this is a recent reference question on how to preserve the identity value when loading data into SQL Server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370325/ssis-auto-increment-field-is-not-inserted-correctly-with-data-flow-task

Comment: If this is not related to identity value, is this just a question of not using ORDER BY ? I mean, when you look at the destination table, are you just doing SELECT * FROM DESTINATION ? The results are not in any order by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ith the ODBC connector.
We had to et the initial statement to:

```
set sql_mode= 'ANSI'
```

[image]